# Can't locate a directory using "locate"?

Tags: command-line, server, locate

I want to locate a directory in my system using "locate" command. I know there is a directory named "bench-repo". when I'm giving the following command it shows me the following error :

```
locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening? How can I find the directory?

Comment: If the directory is new, you have to update the database: `sudo updatedb` and then run your `locate` command again

Comment: @Zanna wow!!! It just worked !!! Thanks a lot, buddy :)

Comment: @Zanna Can you please convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 38):

The binary database used by `locate` (`/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`) is updated once daily by `cron`, so `locate` will not find new files.

You can fix this by first running `sudo updatedb`

```
sudo updatedb && locate -e bench-repo
```

It's a good idea to use the `-e` flag so you only find files that still exist.

Oh and here's a bonus tip - you can get `locate` to give you a detailed listing by passing to `ls -l`

```
ls -l $(locate -e bench-repo)
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Two causes two actions

In general when you are not able to `locate` a file or it is because **recently created** (after the last database update) or because **it is not in the paths** where updatedb is going to search its entries or matches some pruning rules(see below):

1. In case it is a **new file or directory**, If you have enough privilege you can **force an update**:

   ```
   sudo updatedb
   ```

   this will update **all and only** the files and directories present in allowed paths and not discarded (case 2).
2. In case it the file was **out of the paths scanned** by updatedb, or was matching some **exclusions rules** you can modify the configuration file and update the database:

   ```
   sudo pico /etc/updatedb.conf  # manual update
   sudo updatedb
   ```

   Indeed you can find the keys of the pruned files/directories in the configuration file `/etc/updatedb.conf`. Search for `PRUNENAMES`, `PRUNEPATHS` or `PRUNEFS`, modify consequently, then update again the database.

#### Some words more about `locate` and `updatedb`

To be able to `locate` a file or a directory, it has to be actually included in your *mlocate database*, usually stored in `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`.

This database is **updated periodically**. By default it is updated daily and you can see its `cron` file in `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`.  If not present there you can search for it with `locate mlocate | grep cron` and see where it is and how often it is updated.

Use `man locate` and `man updatedb` for further readings.

Comment: Good tip about the PRUNE* variables.

Comment: It happens often on _multiuser_ machine with an area for temporary data or for production data (you know were it is, if it is temporary it doesn't matter, if permanent it is with fixed names...).

Answer (score 7):

Run

```
sudo updatedb
```

before locating. This will update the database.

Comment: Hi PeeKay, I'm afraid that if you are not root you will not be able to run so `updatedb` (that was the reason of `sudo`). Moreover if the file is out of the paths scanned by updatedb (the excluded keys are specified in the PRUNE* variable  of the configuration file `/etc/updatedb.conf`) you will not find it however.

Comment: @Hastur thats true. I thought he would have an idea of how updating a database works